# Highlighting row in one color and blank cell in other color

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to highlight blank cells in yellow but cannot figure out how to also highlight the entire row. The end goal is to have the row highlighted yellow and the blank cell show as red. Not sure if it will be problematic if a row has multiple red/blank cells - I would not want to highlight the full row in yellow again and risk losing the red cells. What I have so far is not much - it has been pieced together through googling and reddit so I apologize if this is sloppy or any lines are unnecessary. I do not know VBA apart from what I've been able to come up with out of necessity. I've been searching forums but have not found much on this specific question. I do have additional requirements - columns L & K are not the only fields that will need checked. I will need to check for duplicate values, expired dates, known incorrect values, etc., but I think once I get this baseline down, I will be able to tweak and customize a more robust macro on my own. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub StatusReportQA()

'delete cognos headers
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
With Sheets("Page1_1")
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & LR)
        If cell = vbNullString Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("L2:L" & LR)
        If cell = vbNullString Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next cell

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Rows(cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6`. That said, is there a reason you cannot use conditional formatting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub StatusReportQA()

    Const MAX_COLS As Long = 20 'for example
    Dim sht As Worksheet, rw As Long
    Dim LR As Long, rngRed As Range, rngRow As Range

    Set sht = Sheets("Page1_1")

    sht.Rows("1:4").Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete cognos headers

    LR = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For rw = 2 To LR
        Set rngRed = Nothing   'reset range for problem cells

        With sht.Rows(rw)
            Set rngRow = .Cells(1).Resize(1, MAX_COLS) 'the row of data
            'clear any previous fill
            rngRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

            'perform your checks
            If Len(.Cells(1, "K").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "K")
            If Len(.Cells(1, "L").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "L")
            'done checking

            If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then
                'found some problems, so color the row and then the problem cells
                rngRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                rngRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If

        End With
    Next rw

End Sub

'utility sub for building a range
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: wow this is more than I was expecting this works perfectly, thank you so much!! you just saved me so much time I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly with Conditional Formatting:

Here I have highlighted a row yellow manually. You can turn yellow highlighting on/off as needed. You can also define specific column ranges a needed or multiple rows as needed.

[image]

Here is the rule:

[image]

Comment: @kms5549 this *is* the best solution - whether done through the Excel UI or programmatically, you want conditional formatting to deal with all of it. Consider coding the conditional formatting instead of evaluating cell values and applying cell formats explicitly - will perform much better, and makes a much better use of Excel's computational power.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub StatusReportQA()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
        'delete cognos headers
        Rows("1:4").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Set WS = Worksheets("Page1_1")
        LR = WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & LR)
            If cell = vbNullString Or cell.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                If cell = vbNullString Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                If cell.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next cell
End Sub
```

Above is some code that gives the expected outcome.  The first thing is that when working with objects in excel (worksheets, cells, ranges, etc) rarely is it required to `.Select` them, and if possible, selecting them should be avoided

to get the desired outcome you have to think about the order in which things need to happen.  First you have to check to see if the cell in either of the columns you are interested in are blank `If cell = vbNullString Or cell.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then` if either of those are blank, you make the highlight the entire row using `cell.EntireRow` to set the color index value.  Then check for which cell is empty and set it's color index value